# How does one change the title of MFMessageComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, sms

I want to change the default title of the SMS controller. How do i do this...
Trying all the normal stuff doesnt work. Anyone know how to do it the right way ?

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(currentContact, kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    [controller setBody:[smsTextView text]];
    [controller setRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0), nil]];
    [controller setMessageComposeDelegate:self];
    //Todo: Make the Title Change
    [controller setTitle:@"asd"];  
    [[controller navigationItem] setTitle:@"asd"];

    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: modal view controllers don't use navigationItem by default. I think your best bet is to loop through controller.views subviews and their subviews etc and check if [subview isKindOfClass:[UINavigationBar class]] or perhaps even [subview respondsToSelector:@selector(setItems:)] from there you can set the item as subview.items = [NSArray arrayWithObject:navigationItem]; obviously navigationItem will be setup by you ;)

Answer (score 1):

I could not get the title to change, but if you'd like to hide the title, you can make the text color transparent:

```
NSDictionary *attributes =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor clearColor],UITextAttributeTextColor, nil];
self.messageComposeVc.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes;
```

Source: [can we change MFmessagecomposeViewcontroller navigtion title font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15516303/can-we-change-mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-navigtion-title-font)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the title of an MFMailComposeViewController instance. (I've been through this myself.) The subject becomes the title, unfortunately, and it is the class itself that makes this happen. There doesn't seem to be a way to defeat that either.

Traversing the subviews to find the nav items might work, but you cannot be guaranteed that the implementation and sub-view hierarchy of MFMailComposeViewController won't change in future iOS releases. So you risk your app breaking if you choose to traverse the tree. And even then, you might not be able to affect the title (if say, the property is read only).

Comment: I guess i'll have to go for the default title then. However i found out that it uses localization. Adding "Localized resources can be mixed: YES" in the info plist at least made it better.

Answer (score -2):

Yes,you can . As MFMessageComposeViewController inherit from UINavigationController , it also has the "navigationBar" property , that belong to the "UINavigationBar" class , and the in the "UINavigationBar" class , there is a "topItem" property , whose class is "UINavigationItem" .
The "topItem" is the current showing item in the UINavigationController. So you can do some custom operation on the "topItem" , such as change the "title","leftBarButtonItem ","rightBarButtonItem" , and so on .
As the code below :

```
// set the SMS navigationBar backgroundColor
controller.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
// set its title
controller.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"your new SMS title" ;
// set the Right Cancel Item's title
controller.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"your SMS cancel title";
```

Relate Apple Doc Referece

[UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[UINavigationBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html)

[UINavigationItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html)

May it help ! You can have a try !